# Vertical rhythm of text lines in multicolumn layout

Tags: html, css, rendering

I need a multicolumn layout, but when I try to create it, and fill it with dummy text, I could see the alignment of text lines is slightly different.

I tested it with flexbox divs and also with two-column `<table>`, but the result is the same. Also I tested it on Chrome and Firefox.

The green lines are showing the identical (that's good) vertical position, while the red ones are showing disproportion.

[image]

*(For testing puposes, the browser window was resized, something like 670 pixels in width)*

- [Fiddle with flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/msk0rs9v/)

- [Fiddle with table](https://jsfiddle.net/w01d5dx1/)

```
<style>
body {
  display: flex;
}
div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}
div:last-of-type {
  flex: 2;
}
</style>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

It could be also just an error in rendering engines, but I don't sure. Maybe, it could be somehow fixed with CSS.

I also tried to specify the precise font-size and line-height, like this:

```
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 110%;
}
```

But it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the margin of the p is 1em. So if you have a paragraph break in a text with a line height of 110% (1.1em), the space between lines is 2.1em, rather than the 2.2em two lines take up normally.

Solution: set the margin to the same value as the line height.

```css
p {
  /* font-size: doesn't matter */
  line-height: 110%;
  margin: 1.1em 0; /* same as line-height */
}
```

Edit:
It seems that the browsers display the line-heights in a different way. If the line-height is not a whole number of pixels, Chrome rounds the value and uses that. Firefox apparently remembers the fraction and uses that when calculating the next one. So if the value would be 17.4 pixels, Firefox uses 17 pixels for the first two lines and 18 pixels for the next. IE11 does that too.
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/dwxk1x04/2/) for an example (using 2.4 pixels).

I am not sure there is a solution for that, other than to set the line-height to a specific number of pixels that is not a percentage of the font size.

```css
p {
  /* font-size: now does matter, sorry */
  line-height: 18px; /* or anything appropriate */
  margin: 18px 0; /* same as line height */
}
```

Comment: Well, it's a bit strange. The issue seems to be fixed in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry about that; I obviously was assuming that basic CSS1 properties such as these would be handled the same by all browsers these days. See edited post for a workaround.

Comment: Seems to work. Thank you very much for interesting things to know! :-) Do I understand right, that I can take any font size, next I should specify `line-height` and `margin` in pixels a bit larger than font size and that's enough to make it work properly?

Comment: Usually, yes. In most cases, it's best to specify the line-height as relative to the font size. The default is usually about 1.2. Then you won't run into situations where you forget to set it and end up with the wrong line height for the font. So use fixed values like this only for specialised situations like in here.